# Implement payments inside a Codename One app

Tags: codenameone

What are the most recent info and/or tool about in-app purchases with Codename One? My target is paid posts in a social app.

Baintree?

Or: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/intro-to-in-app-purchase.html ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different things that serve different purposes. In your case I think In-App-Purchase is the only option.

Apple and Google prohibit credit card payment for "virtual items" but also prohibit in app payment for physical items. E.g. you can't charge for an App Upgrade using credit card (braintree is effectively a credit card charging solution). You also can't charge for lunch or a taxi using in-app-purchase.

Comment: Ok. Is https://www.codenameone.com/blog/intro-to-in-app-purchase.html updated or are there more recent info or tutorial about that?

Comment: It's pretty much up to date as far as I recall